# Merge XML files in PHP

Tags: php, xml, merge

I have 2 files `1.xml` and `2.xml` both having similar structure and I would like to have one. I tried many solutions but I had errors only - frankly speaking I have no idea how those scripts worked.

`1.xml`:

```xml
<res>
    <items total="180">
        <item>
            <id>1</id>
            <title>Title 1</title>
            <author>Author 1</author>
        </item>
        ...
    </items>
</res>
```

`2.xml`:

```xml
<res>
    <items total="123">
        <item>
            <id>190</id>
            <title>Title 190</title>
            <author>Author 190</author>
        </item>
        ...
    </items>
</res>
```

I would like to create a new file `merged.xml` with the following structure

```xml
<res>
    <items total="303">
        <item>
            <id>1</id>
            <title>Title 1</title>
            <author>Author 1</author>
        </item>
        ...  //items from 1.xml
        <item>
            <id>190</id>
            <title>Title 190</title>
            <author>Author 190</author>
        </item>
        ... //items from 2.xml
    </items>
</res>
```

How should I do that? Can you explain me the way to do it? How can I do it with more files? Thanks

**Edit**

What I tried?

```php
<?php
function mergeXML(&$base, $add)
{
    if ( $add->count() != 0 )
    $new = $base->addChild($add->getName());
    else
        $new = $base->addChild($add->getName(), $add);
    foreach ($add->attributes() as $a => $b)
    {
        $new->addAttribute($a, $b);
    }
    if ( $add->count() != 0 )
    {
       foreach ($add->children() as $child)
        {
            mergeXML($new, $child);
        }
    }
}
$xml = mergeXML(simplexml_load_file('1.xml'), simplexml_load_file('2.xml'));
echo $xml->asXML(merged.xml);
?>
```

**EDIT2**

Following Torious advice I looked into DOMDocument manual and found an example:

```php
function joinXML($parent, $child, $tag = null)
{
    $DOMChild = new DOMDocument;
    $DOMChild->load($child);
    $node = $DOMChild->documentElement;

    $DOMParent = new DOMDocument;
    $DOMParent->formatOutput = true;
    $DOMParent->load($parent);

    $node = $DOMParent->importNode($node, true);

    if ($tag !== null) {
        $tag = $DOMParent->getElementsByTagName($tag)->item(0);
        $tag->appendChild($node);
    } else {
        $DOMParent->documentElement->appendChild($node);
    }

    return $DOMParent->save('merged.xml');
}

joinXML('1.xml', '2.xml')
```

But it creates wrong xml file:

```xml
<res>
    <items total="180">
        <item>
            <id>1</id>
            <title>Title 1</title>
            <author>Author 1</author>
        </item>
        ...
    </items>
    <res>
        <items total="123">
            <item>
                <id>190</id>
                <title>Title 190</title>
                <author>Author 190</author>
            </item>
            ...
        </items>
    </res> 
</res>
```

And I cannot use this file properly. I need correct structure and here I have kind of pasting one file into another. I would like to "paste" only item's not all tags. What should I change?

EDIT3

here is an answer - based on Torious answer - just adapted it to my needs - check //edited

```
$doc1 = new DOMDocument();
$doc1->load('1.xml');

$doc2 = new DOMDocument();
$doc2->load('2.xml');

// get 'res' element of document 1
$res1 = $doc1->getElementsByTagName('items')->item(0); //edited res - items

// iterate over 'item' elements of document 2
$items2 = $doc2->getElementsByTagName('item');
for ($i = 0; $i < $items2->length; $i ++) {
    $item2 = $items2->item($i);

    // import/copy item from document 2 to document 1
    $item1 = $doc1->importNode($item2, true);

    // append imported item to document 1 'res' element
    $res1->appendChild($item1);

}
$doc1->save('merged.xml'); //edited -added saving into xml file
```

Comment: Try using the DOM, start [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php). Note that if you want to merge XML documents (from different `DOMDocument` sources, you'll have to use `importNode` (or so) at some point in time.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since you've put an effort in, I've coded something that should work.

*Note that this is untested code, but you get the idea.*

It's up to you to make it into pretty functions. Make sure you understand what's going on; being able to work with the DOM will probably help you out in a lot of future scenarios. The cool thing about the DOM standard is that you have pretty much the same operations in many different programming languages/platforms.

```
    $doc1 = new DOMDocument();
    $doc1->load('1.xml');

    $doc2 = new DOMDocument();
    $doc2->load('2.xml');

    // get 'res' element of document 1
    $res1 = $doc1->getElementsByTagName('res')->item(0);

    // iterate over 'item' elements of document 2
    $items2 = $doc2->getElementsByTagName('item');
    for ($i = 0; $i < $items2->length; $i ++) {
        $item2 = $items2->item($i);

        // import/copy item from document 2 to document 1
        $item1 = $doc1->importNode($item2, true);

        // append imported item to document 1 'res' element
        $res1->appendChild($item1);

    }
```

Comment: thank you for solution - i had to change few things - check edit3 section //edit - means that i changed a line

Comment: You can iterate over `DOMNodeList`, so your for loop is better-written as `foreach($doc2->getElementsByTagName('item') as $item2)`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most simplest way is changing XML to array first, combine two array which are much more easier and straightforward. Finally change array back to xml. It may helps for the situation when you want to combine two XML files directly. You only need to consider which key is the position you wanna add the child nodes.

```
function xml_to_array($sxi){
    $a = array();
    for( $sxi->rewind(); $sxi->valid(); $sxi->next() ) {
        if(!array_key_exists($sxi->key(), $a)){
            $a[$sxi->key()] = array();
        }
        if($sxi->hasChildren()){
            $a[$sxi->key()] = $this->xml_to_array($sxi->current());
        }
        else{
            $a[$sxi->key()] = strval($sxi->current());
        }
    }
    return $a;
}
function array_to_xml( $data, &$xml_data ) {
    foreach( $data as $key => $value ) {
        if( is_numeric($key) ){
            $key = 'item'.$key; //dealing with <0/>..<n/> issues
        }
        if( is_array($value) ) {
            $subnode = $xml_data->addChild($key);
            array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
        } else {
            $xml_data->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
        }
    }
}
```

Useage: Create a  SimpleXMLIterator

```
$xml1 = new \SimpleXMLIterator('test1.xml',null,true);
$a = xml_to_array($xml1); //convert xml to array
$xml2 = new \SimpleXMLIterator('test2.xml',null,true);
$b = xml_to_array($xml2);
$c = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0"?><data></data>');
$a['new_node']=$b;
array_to_xml($a,$c);
var_dump($c);
```

Answer (score -2):

How about :

```
<?php
// Read file 1
$xmlfilecontent = file_get_contents('xml1.xml');

// Concat file 2
$xmlfilecontent .= file_get_contents('xml2.xml');

// remove <items> tags
preg_replace('/<items[^"]*">/','',$xmlfilecontent);

// remove </items> tags
$xmlfilecontent = str_replace('</items>','',$xmlfilecontent );

// remove <res> tags
$xmlfilecontent = str_replace('<res>','',$xmlfilecontent );

// remove </res> tags
$xmlfilecontent = str_replace('</res>','',$xmlfilecontent );

// load XML Object - also add res and items + amount
$xmlobj = simple_xml_load_string('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>'.PHP_EOL.'<res>'.PHP_EOL.'<items total="'.substr_count( $xmlfilecontent , '<item>').'">'.PHP_EOL.$xmlfilecontent.PHP_EOL.'</items>'.PHP_EOL.'</res>');
```