# How to change a php code to merge any number of XML files

Tags: php, xml, merge

Here the working code (i took [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163675/merge-xml-files-in-php)) to merge two XML files into one. It is working properly, but only with 2 parts of xml.

```
<?php
$numparts=2;
$filename1='TEST_1.xml';
$filename2='TEST_2.xml';
$doc1 = new DOMDocument();
$doc1->load($filename1);

$doc2 = new DOMDocument();
$doc2->load($filename2);

// get 'res' element of document 1
$res1 = $doc1->getElementsByTagName('items')->item(0); //edited res - items

// iterate over 'item' elements of document 2
$items2 = $doc2->getElementsByTagName('item');

for ($i = 0; $i < $items2->length; $i ++) {
$item2 = $items2->item($i);

// import/copy item from document 2 to document 1
$item1 = $doc1->importNode($item2, true);

// append imported item to document 1 'res' element
$res1->appendChild($item1);
}
$doc1->save('merged.xml'); //edited -added saving into xml file
?>
```

Please help to change the code to work with any number of pieces (stored in the variable $numparts).

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Simply put it in a loop and merge couples of files. so if you have 3 files: merge doc1 with doc2 into doc12 and then merge doc12 with doc 3, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, using loops, create arrays of the filenames, and their corresponding documents that you wish to merge.

```
$numparts = 3;
// Create an array of $numparts filenames of the xml files you wish to merge
$filenames = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= $numparts; $i++) {
    $filenames[$i] = 'TEST_' . $i . '.xml';
}
// Create an array of DOM Document objects, one for each xml file
$docs = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($filenames); $i++) {
    $docs[$i] = new DOMDocument();
    $docs[$i]->load($filenames[$i]);
}
```

Then create a loop that iterates over all but the first document and nest the loop that iterates of the items in a document (the one in your code sample) within this.

```
// get 'res' element of document 1
$doc1 = $docs[1];
 $res1 = $doc1->getElementsByTagName('items')->item(0); //edited res - items
// iterate over all the rest of the documents
for ($i = 2; $i <= count($docs); $i++) {
    $doci = $docs[$i];
    // iterate over 'item' elements of document i
    $itemsi = $doci->getElementsByTagName('item');
    for ($j = 0; $j < $itemsi->length; $j++) {
        $itemi = $itemsi->item($j);
        // import/copy item from document i to document 1
        $item1 = $doc1->importNode($itemi, true);
        // append imported item to document 1 'res' element
        $res1->appendChild($item1);
    }
}
$doc1->save('merged.xml'); //edited -added saving into xml file
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works great! I tried loops for, while, nothing worked. I am ashamed of my mistakes and ignorance of PHP.
Thanks again!