# simplexml load multiple files at once

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm using XML to fetch some language data.

The XML markup is as follows:

```
<language>
    <item>
        <key>KEY</key>
        <string>STRING</string>
    </item>
    <item>
        ....
    </item>
</language>
```

I have 2 XML-files with the **same markup**. I want to load them both with simplexml_load_file. Does anyone know what's the best approach to do this?

I tried something like this:

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('...url_file_1...');
    $xml .= simplexml_load_file('...url_file_2...');
?>
```

But thats not working. But thats what I want: all the data from the 2 (and eventually more) files in one variable.

**Edit:** I want to make use of the simpleXML library if possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge XML files in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163675/merge-xml-files-in-php)

Comment: @splash58, possibly yes, but I want to keep the files separated (for easy translation in the future) so I do not want to make one, big file.. I'm afraid it will take some time to merge the files first every time a visitor opens a page before the tags kan be parsed.

Comment: `$res1` is object with data from both files which are not joined, i think

Comment: You can use the SimpleXmlIterator for each file and add that to a MultipleIterator or AppendIterator. That would allow you to iterate both DOMs from one Iterator. But I somewhat doubt that this is what you are looking for.