# Writing and Appending to an XML file

Tags: php, xml, laravel

Hello I found the following code online that creates and adds data to an xml file:

```
public function index()
    {
        $html = "";

        try {
            $employees = array();
            $employees [] = array(
                'name' => 'Albert',
                'age' => '34',
                'salary' => "$10000"
            );
            $employees [] = array(
                'name' => 'Claud',
                'age' => '20',
                'salary' => "$2000"
            );

            $doc = new DOMDocument();
            $doc->formatOutput = true;

            $r = $doc->documentElement->firstChild;
            $doc->appendChild( $r );

            foreach( $employees as $employee )
            {
                $b = $doc->createElement( "employee" );

                $name = $doc->createElement( "name" );
                $name->appendChild(
                    $doc->createTextNode( $employee['name'] )
                );
                $b->appendChild( $name );

                $age = $doc->createElement( "age" );
                $age->appendChild(
                    $doc->createTextNode( $employee['age'] )
                );
                $b->appendChild( $age );

                $salary = $doc->createElement( "salary" );
                $salary->appendChild(
                    $doc->createTextNode( $employee['salary'] )
                );
                $b->appendChild( $salary );

                $r->appendChild( $b );
            }

            $doc->save(".." . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "storage" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "logs" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "employees.xml") ;


            return response()->json();
        }
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            return response()->json(
                [
                    "message" => $e->getMessage(),
                    "status_code" => $e->getCode(),
                    "data" => []
                ]);
        }

    }
```

This is the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<employees>
  <employee>
    <name>Albert</name>
    <age>34</age>
    <salary>$10000</salary>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <name>Claud</name>
    <age>20</age>
    <salary>$2000</salary>
  </employee>
</employees>
```

However when I run the code again it gives the same output.  I would like the new output to be appended to the previous data in the xml file so that I have this instead:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <employees>
      <employee>
        <name>Albert</name>
        <age>34</age>
        <salary>$10000</salary>
      </employee>
      <employee>
        <name>Claud</name>
        <age>20</age>
        <salary>$2000</salary>
      </employee>
      <employee>
        <name>Albert</name>
        <age>34</age>
        <salary>$10000</salary>
      </employee>
      <employee>
    <name>Claud</name>
    <age>20</age>
    <salary>$2000</salary>
  </employee>
</employees>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the script is always writing to the same file - so it is overwriting the old file.

**Solution 1:**

The easiest way is to append a timestamp to your the file name, like so:

```
$doc->save(".." . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "storage" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "logs" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "employees-".date("Y/m/d - h:m:s").".xml") ;
```

For each run of the script you get a separate file with the new content.

**Solution 2:**

To append the new data to the old one, you need to load the old file first, and then append it with the new content. `DOMDocument` has no method or function to append new content to old ones automatically.

So after of doing

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
```

you can [load](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php) the already existing file with

```
$oldContent = $doc->load(<PATH TO YOUR XML FILE>);
```

Now you can merge both and save them. How to merge those two files has been explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163675/merge-xml-files-in-php) in detail.

Comment: You mean I cannot append data to the same XML file?