# How to merge multiple XML files in PHP

Tags: php, xml, merge

I am new to PHP programming and would appreciate whatever help i can get. I have an Xml file that looks like below..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <results>
        <test external_id="123">
           <result>p</result>
        </test>
        <test external_id="1237">
           <result>p</result>
        </test>
        <test external_id="234">
           <result>p</result>
        </test>
        <test external_id="678">
            <result>p</result>
        </test>
     </results>
```

The XML file is generated from a testrun. Now sometimes the test could break and would restart generating another xml file which might contain similar values as generated in the first xml file. For example, Xml file 2 might contain the following values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <results>
     <test external_id="412">
        <result>p</result>
     </test>
     <test external_id="234">
        <result>p</result>
     </test>
     <test external_id="123">
        <result>p</result>
     </test>
     <test external_id="745">
        <result>p</result>
     </test>
    </results>
```

I need to write a PHP script to merge the different XML files generated into a single XML file without duplicates. Only one occurrence of (test external_id = "XXX")should be in the final xml file. There could be more than 2 XML files generated during the test run. I have searched through the various solutions given on stackoverflow but can't get it. I have been able to merge the files but the duplicates are still there.What I have written so far. Thanks for your anticipated help.

```
<?php

$doc1 = new DOMDocument();
$doc1->load('11.xml');

$doc2 = new DOMDocument();
$doc2->load('12.xml');

// get 'results' element of document 1
$res1 = $doc1->getElementsByTagName('results')->item(0);

// iterate over 'testcase' elements of document 2
$items2 = $doc2->getElementsByTagName('test');
for ($i = 0; $i < $items2->length; $i ++) {
        $item2 = $items2->item($i);

// import/copy item from document 2 to document 1
 $item1 = $doc1->importNode($item2, true);

// append imported item to document 1 'res' element
$res1->appendChild($item1);

    }

$doc1->save('merged.xml'); //saving into xml file


$seen=array();

$doc3 = new DOMDocument();
$doc3->load('merged.xml');

$results = $doc3->getElementsByTagName('test');
foreach($results as $test){
    //$key=$doc3->$test;
    if (isset($seen[$test])) {
        unset($doc3->$test);
    }else{
        $seen[$test]=1;
    }
}

echo $doc3->asXML();
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge XML files in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163675/merge-xml-files-in-php)

Comment: Is this a homework?

Comment: "_I need to write a PHP script_ ..." Then do that. Post your code if you have any and get stuck somewhere

Comment: @WaqasBukhary, I have tried that and it actually merges the files but with duplicates. I need only one occurrence of each test. How can I modify the script to remove duplicates

Comment: `$seen=array();

$doc3 = new DOMDocument();
$doc3->load('merged.xml');

$results = $doc3->getElementsByTagName('test');
foreach($results as $test){
    //$key=$doc3->$test;
    if (isset($seen[$test])) {
        unset($doc3->$test);
    }else{
        $seen[$test]=1;
    }
}

echo $doc3->asXML();`

Comment: Your question don't have a problem statement... Your question is basic php and xml, try to post a question when you have tried something thoroughly and have failed. https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @WaqasBukhary, I just posted the code i wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

With the two files you have, it's easier to take 1 file and add the elements in from the other.  First it checks if the node already exists (using XPath and counting the number of elements that have the same ID).  If the node doesn't already exist, it has to first import the node from the one document to the other and then add it to the root element.

```
$doc1 = new DOMDocument();
$doc1->load('NewFile.xml');   // Change file names as needed.
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc1);

$doc2 = new DOMDocument();
$doc2->load('NewFile1.xml');

$test1 = $doc2->getElementsByTagName('test');
foreach ( $test1 as $testItem ) {
    $id = $testItem->getAttribute('external_id');
    if ( $xp->evaluate("count(//test[@external_id='{$id}'])") == 0 )  {
        $copyNode = $doc1->importNode($testItem, true);
        $doc1->documentElement->appendChild($copyNode);
    }
}

echo $doc1->saveXML();
```

XPath isn't the quickest thing to run, but it's easier to do it this way rather than having to loop through the document (IMHO).

This isn't the best solution if you have large files as it holds all the content in memory for both documents.