# Combine multiple XML from JSON convertion

Tags: php, arrays, json, xml

I am collecting data from API in JSON and converting it to XML. Now all data cant be collected at once so I can get only 100 items in one run and convert each JSON response to XML and create a separate file for each.
i am using variable $i for incrementing Page for JSON and using same to create a file for XML.

main important data is in  so if possible i want only those data to be added in xml file.

```
function arrayToXml($array, &$xml){

    foreach($array as $key => $value) {

      if(is_array($value)) {
        if(!is_numeric($key)){
            $subnode = $xml->addChild("$key");
            arrayToXml($value, $subnode);
        }else{
            $subnode = $xml->addChild("item$key");
            arrayToXml($value, $subnode);
        }
    }else {

        $xml->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
    }
}
```

}

```
$file=curl_exec($ch);

$array = json_decode ($file, true);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
arrayToXml($array, $xml);
$result = $xml->asXML($i.'name.xml');
```

```html
<results>
<item0>
<_class>course</_class>
<id>364426</id>
<title>JavaScript: Understanding the Weird Parts</title>
<url>/understand-javascript/</url>
   
<headline>
An advanced JavaScript course for everyone! Scope, closures, prototypes, 'this', build your own framework, and more.
</headline>
<num_subscribers>100604</num_subscribers>
<avg_rating>4.77</avg_rating>
<num_reviews>23000</num_reviews>
<num_lectures>85</num_lectures>
<primary_subcategory>
<id>8</id>
<_class>course_subcategory</_class>
<title>Web Development</title>
</primary_subcategory>
<predictive_score/>
<relevancy_score>1.0704279</relevancy_score>
<input_features/>
<lecture_search_result/>
</item0>
```

```html
<root>
<count>8373</count>
<next>...</next>
<previous/>
<results>...</results>
<aggregations>...</aggregations>
</root>
```

In short I want data of every iteration in one XML file and if possible only data with key results and their child. as shown above.
I want only  to be added in xml file from all json response.

Comment: This is a previous answer I've written on merging XML files, see if it helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48905154/combining-xml-files-in-php/48905373#48905373

Comment: Actually i want to append new data got from JSON to xml file. and i got almost 100 of pages to convert from json to xml. So i was thinking to doo all at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add the new results to an existing XML file, it can be done using something like...

```
$fileName = "data.xml";
if ( file_exists($fileName))    {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($fileName);
}
else    {
    $xml= new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
}
$array = json_decode ($file, true);
arrayToXml($array, $xml);
$xml->asXML($fileName);
```

So instead of creating a new XML structure each time, it loads any existing data(if there is any), adds the new data in and then writes it back to the data file.

I'm not sure what you mean by 'if possible only data with key results', if you can expand on this I may be able to help.

**Update:**

I've updated the code with the extra information, think this fits what your after...

```
function arrayToXml($array, &$xml){
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            if(!is_numeric($key)){
                $subnode = $xml->addChild("$key");
                arrayToXml($value, $subnode);
            }else{
                $subnode = $xml->addChild("course");
                arrayToXml($value, $subnode);
            }
        }else {
            $xml->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
        }
    }
}

if ( file_exists($fileName))    {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($fileName);
}
else    {
    $xml= new SimpleXMLElement('<results />');
}
$array = json_decode ($file, true);
// Remove _class element
foreach ( $array['results'] as $key=>$result )   {
    unset($array['results'][$key]['_class']);
}
arrayToXml($array['results'], $xml);
$xml->asXML($fileName);
```

Main things I've done is to change the root element for a new document to `<results />`, each item is added as 'course' instead of 'item?', and when adding the new data, I start at `$array['results']` instead of the base of the data.

I've added some code to remove the `_class` item from each element, this could be expanded to other items if needed - or removed if you want to retain this info.

**Update**

```
function arrayToXml($array, &$xml){
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            if(!is_numeric($key)){
                if ($key == "visible_instructors") {
                    $vi =  $xml->addChild($key);
                    $subnode = $vi->addChild("instructor");
                    arrayToXml($value[0], $subnode);
                }
                else {
                    $subnode = $xml->addChild($key);
                    arrayToXml($value, $subnode);
                }
            }
            else {
                    $subnode = $xml->addChild("course");
                    arrayToXml($value, $subnode);
            }
        }else {
            $xml->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
        }
    }
}
```

Your test was in the wrong branch of the `if(!is_numeric($key)){`, it was working with numeric values, which PHP helpfully converts and produces odd results at times.  This code checks if the non numeric key is `visible_instructors` and adjusts the content accordingly.

Comment: after convertion their are useless data and i am intrested in <results> all child </results> instead of <root>
<count>8373</count>
<next>...</next>
<previous/>
<results>...</results>
<aggregations>...</aggregations>
</root>

Comment: Thanks it works. but its creating duplicate key. is it possible to add data in existing tree. like i have <results> all child data </results>  now i want all child data of new xml to be in existing <results> tree.

Comment: Can you give a couple of small sample JSON files as well as how they should look in the final result, it will make it easier make it as you want.

Comment: Here is json data. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NBPHaCCapff7Jmicc_2ZBalPJ0issC9s/view?usp=sharing      I want to convert to xml and get selected data from results array. i am planning to use xmp for bulk import so data need to be in tree like <results><data1>Data1</data1></results> all the data from iterations should be inside <results>

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ikhfQ5AwW2Iov5-bID_3UNvL0B3PJHM5/view?usp=sharing here is example xml file i want.

Comment: Updated answer, the example data is sometimes the best way of showing what you need.

Comment: !00% Perfect Code.. Thanks Sir.

Comment: Is it possible to add new iteration data <course> on top instead of bottom in results tree... it's not necessary but useful for import script as it can get fresh data on top.

Comment: SimpleXML can't add at a specific point, but if you converted it to using DOMDocument, you can use insertBefore() to create them in a specific order.

Comment: No Problem. But there is one issue there is one more <course> child inside <course> there is nested course. i have added. if condition to check $key value and replace course key but it's not working for 1st item. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YAKvVBsU4QYLRfsFOpzXKKimm7kyA8-q/view?usp=sharing   i added if condition to check if its visible_instructor and changed course to the instructor but for first item course is converted to instructor and from seconf ited all good.

Comment: Without code I can't work out what is happening - and without the data your trying to add it's difficult to know what it's trying to deal with.

Comment: here is the code.    https://drive.google.com/file/d/1INNn_GD_Lrm0szfO1LNl3cwjQ09tEwdZ/view?usp=sharing   that i used to prevent course child inside course. and result is in above file.

Comment: As I can't download it, can you send me the JSON which causes this entry to be created.

Comment: Code: https://www.a2zsaving.review/test/code.txt    Result: 
 https://www.a2zsaving.review/test/data.xml     JSON:  https://www.a2zsaving.review/test/test.json   Output in image format: 
 https://imgur.com/a/cjjtq   Code is the modified code that i added to prevent <course> inside <course> parent. Result is the output which is correct from second items but first item parent is not <course>

Comment: OK - I'll have a look

Comment: have a look at this image you will understand https://imgur.com/a/cjjtq