# Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to DOMNode::appendChild() must be an instance of DOMNode, bool given

Tags: php, domdocument

I have a function I am using to generate a chunk of html and which returns a DOMDocument, I am then trying to append that DOMDocument to an existing element I have using a foreach construct I found in a user comment on the DOMDocument documentation page. It is the part throwing the error and in my case it looks like this:

```
foreach($eventForm->childNodes as $e) {
    $tabPane->appendChild($tabDom->importNode($e, true));
}
```

When I `get_class($e)`, I am only getting 2 children, a DOMDocumentType and a single DOMElement. The single element makes sense but I don't know why its giving me the DOMDocumentType object as a child node or what to do about it.

Should I just add a `if(get_class() != DOMDocumentType)` to the for loop or is there some better way to append one DOMDocument to another element? I was getting a 'wrong document' error before I used this loop.

Comment: For merging two files, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163675/merge-xml-files-in-php may give you a solution.

Comment: This error is very clear. `appendChild` is getting passed a `bool` but it expects a `DomNode`. So check your values before you pass them. https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php#refsect1-domdocument.importnode-returnvalues